# Creating leaflet.minicharts popup labels for many different plots

Tags: r, dplyr, r-leaflet

I am using R leaflet.minicharts to create plots for each of several input files. I would like to create custom labels for each of the pie charts or bar plots within each minichart plot, but am having trouble with the code.

I have a data frame (df) similar to the following:

> ```
>     location grp1 grp2 grp3 grp4
> 1   loc1     1    0    0    0
> 2   loc2     0    5    0    1
> 3   loc3     1    0    3    0
> 4   loc4     0    2    2    2
> 5   loc5     0    1    0    7
> ```

And would like to create a popup label for each pie chart (or barplot) within each plot that follows this format:

> ```
> loc1
> grp1: 1
> grp2: 0
> grp3: 0
> grp4: 0
> ```

Based on another post ([Leaflet for R: Display several data rows in popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928533/leaflet-for-r-display-several-data-rows-in-popup)) I see that my label format should be as follows:

> ```
> my_popups <- df %>%
>    group_by(location) %>%
>    mutate(popup = paste0("<h3>", location,
>    paste("grp1:", grp1, "<b>", "grp2:", grp2, "<b>", "grp3:", grp3, "<b>", "grp4:", grp4, "<b>", collapse = "<br>"))) %>%
>    pull(popup)
> ```

But how can I automate my_popups to generate custom labels for several different input files that will have varying levels for grp (e.g. grp1 through grp4 is shown here, but I also have inputs for grp1 through grp5, and so on). I don't want to manually enter the "paste" portion of this code for every input.

I've created a vector with a portion of my data frame column names as follows:

> ```
> [1] "grp1"     "grp2"     "grp3"     "grp4"
> ```

I'm thinking there should be a way to paste this in the correct format for my_popups, but am not quite sure how to proceed. Any tips will be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could do the trick maybe, probable, surely, with some minor changes:

```
cols <- colnames(df)     
coln <- cols[grepl("grp", cols)]
coln <- paste0("<b>",coln[2:length(coln)],":" )
coln<-c(coln, "<b>")
df$popup <- apply(df[,-1],1,paste,coln,collapse="") 
df %>% mutate(popup = paste0("<h3>", location,"grp1:", popup))
```

A few small tweaks to get the exact formatting @nrcombs wanted:

```
cols <- colnames(df)     
coln <- cols[grepl("grp", cols)]
coln <- paste0("<br>",coln[2:length(coln)],": " )
coln<-c(coln, "<br>")
df$popup <- apply(df[,-1],1,paste,coln,collapse="") 
df %>% mutate(popup = paste0("<h3>", location, "</h3><br>", "grp1: ", popup))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @JonnyCrunch!

Comment: I just made a few small edits to @JonnyCrunch code to get the exact formatting I want (vertical orientation of Grp# rather than horizontal), thanks again!